# springdoc-openapi swagger-ui behind proxy configuration

Tags: spring-boot, proxy, swagger

I have added swagger-ui on a spring boot 2.3.1 app, it works fine locally.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
        <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.9</version>
    </dependency>
```

This application is deployed in a kubernetes cluster but it's not accessible (no ingress)

Instead we deployed another spring boot app that is accessible and can call this service.
API calls get redirected fine but swagger-ui does not work.

Basically, my proxy app is accessible like this :
https://app-dev.domain.io/proxy-service/v2/my-service/**

=> https://app-dev.domain.io/proxy-service/v2/my-service/swagger-ui.html

In my proxy service, I set the X-Forwarded headers like this :

X-Forwarded-Host = Host header (app-dev.domain.io)

X-Forwarded-Proto = https

X-Forwarded-Prefix = /proxy-service/v2/my-service/

I also set the header Accept-Encoding=identity

The proxy service then calls http://my-service inside the cluster

In MyService configuration I set :
server.forward-headers-strategy=framework

It seems to find static files, but i get javascript errors and a blank page :
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
swagger-ui-standalone-preset.js:21 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
index.html?configUrl=/proxy-service/v2/my-service/v3/api-docs/swagger-config:41 Uncaught ReferenceError: SwaggerUIBundle is not defined
at window.onload

From what I have searched, I did what was needed (headers-strategy in called service and X-Forwarded in proxy)

Any help would be awesome, as I would like for the services to be easily testable without maintaining a postman collection manually or something similar. ( always forgotten at some point )
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out that the javascript files are getting truncated.
So the javascript errors make sense.
I'll try again after fixing this

Edit :
It is now working with the complete javascript files.
I used HttpURLConnection instead of RestTemplate which tuncates the files for no reason